# Função Mouse Tela

Tags: javascript

Essa função que captura o movimento do mouse não funciona ,  o que esta errado nela como corrigir ?

```
    <script>
        $(document).bind("mouseleave", function(e) {
            if (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() <= 1) {
                alert('Tem certeza que quer fechar a aba? :(');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É mais próximo que pode chegar

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    // $("body").html("posição do mouse: " + (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()))
    if ((e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()) == 0){
      alert('Tem certeza que quer fechar a aba? :(');
    }
});

// Ou

$(window).mouseleave(function() {
   alert('Tem certeza que quer fechar a aba? :(');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, Wéllingthon M. de Souza !